# HTTPUrlConnection maintain session

Tags: java, session, session-cookies

I am using Restful Services on server and trying to maintain the same session after performing login:

```
URL endpoint = new URL(getString(R.string.url_login));
// Create connection
HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) endpoint.openConnection();
myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
myConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "my-rest-app-v0.1");
// Create the data
String myData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + pwd;
// Enable data writing
myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
// Write the data
myConnection.getOutputStream().write(myData.getBytes());
rc = myConnection.getResponseCode();
if (rc == 200) {
        String  Cookie= myConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        URL endpoint2 = new URL(getString(R.string.url_checkUserType));
        HttpURLConnection myConnection2 = 
                 (HttpURLConnection)endpoint2.openConnection();
        myConnection2.setRequestMethod("GET");
        myConnection2.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "my-rest-app-v0.1");
        myConnection2.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Cookie);
        rc2 = myConnection2.getResponseCode();
....
        }....
```

The problem is that rc2 is every time 401 as WebService doesn't recognize that requiest is part of the same session. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The solution was to use [Spring RESTful services for Android](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/) that worked great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [Spring RESTful services](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) for Android that worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows

1. on the server side, it checks if the incoming request has a "sessionId" in cookie: if not, create one and return it in response; if yes, it knows the request belongs to a known session
2. on the client side, after a successful login, retrieve the "sessionId" from the response, and set it in the following requests

==

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + URLEncoder.encode(jSessionId, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: why do I need to encode jSessionId?
A variable `Cookie` contains string like `JSESSIONID=FA4D1226F11D2EBCB85361D5D9CA703F; Path=/My_Server; HttpOnly`
it seems that you are doing the same or not?

Comment: It is to translates a string into application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, not any character is allowed in URL.

Comment: But if it is returned by server it should be allowed? Any way Spring Security (*what I use on server side ) still rejects it

Comment: Encoding of jSessionId is not required, depending on how the id is generated. If you are using Spring Security, and it is not configured as `stateless`, then the session id is already there, and you just need to set it when sending next requests. If this does not work, what error do you see on the server log?

Comment: it fails on authorization part : `http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/restapii/*").authenticated()`
So that's why I get `unauthorized` . if I change on `.permitAll()` it works (obviously). I am sure there are no errors on server side as it works perfectly from browser and this code is for MobileApp

Comment: The log seems to be quite brief, changing the log level to DEBUG will provide you a lot more details. Also, as it works with browser, you may take a look at the developer console of the browser, look at the request header and body, to see what is sent by the browser, which may give you a reference to the request sent with your own implementation.

Comment: seems I do everything correctly...but as usual: nothing works